# integration involving Hermit function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, orthogonal-polynomials

Iam trying to evaluate the integration of the following two products .. every one by itself
[image]

where Hn-1 is the Hermite function .
All my tries ends with a zero value for the two integrations, but it must not . Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $\forall n \neq k$ $$\langle H_{n}, H_{k} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H_{n}(x)H_{k}(x)e^{-x^{2}/2}dx$$
is identically zero implying that $H_{n}$ and $H_{k}$ are orthogonal. A lemma naturally follows;

**Lemma 1.**
$$\int H_{n+1}e^{-x^{2}/2}dx=C-H_{n}e^{-x^{2}/2}$$
Where $C$ is a constannt. I suspect these relations will help you find your answer, by the weay my opinion is that I'm not surpised you're finding zeroes to the answer.

**Edit**
Based on the requirement in the comment to this post, I will post a few observations, I will not go into the inductive proof.

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int x e^{-x^{2}/2}dx &=& -e^{-x^{2}/2}+C \\
\int (x^{2}-1)e^{-x^{2}/2}dx &=& -xe^{-x^{2}/2}+C \\
\int (x^{3}-3x)e^{-x^{2}/2}dx &=& -(x^{2}-1)e^{-x^{2}/2}+c
\end{eqnarray}

**Further Edit**
Also note that for *general* $n$
$$x^{n}=H_{n}(x)+a_{n-1}H_{n-1}(x)+a_{n-2}H_{n-2}(x)+ \ldots a_{1}H_{1}(x)+a_{0}H_{0}(x)$$

Comment: can you show how this lemma comes?

Comment: Sure I'll edit my post to reflect requirements.